# Populating the ForeignSecurityPrincipals Container?

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to figure out how to populate the ForeignSecurityPrinipals container that is built-in to Active Directory. I have added foreign members to groups in my domain which is how I though this was populated, but the container still remains empty. Am I going about this the completely wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no manual intervention with the ForeignSecurityPrinicpals container required.

You don't say if the objects you're expecting to see come from domains foreign to your forest. You're only going to see objects created in that container for security principals from foreign domains / forests. Principals from other domains within your forest won't create entries in the ForeignSecurityPrincipals container (because information about them is already available in the Global Catalog).

Answer (score 0):

From Mastering Active Directory for Windows Server 2003:

> Foreign Security Principals Container When a **trust** is made **with a domain outside of the
>   tree**, this container is used to hold references to objects from the outside environment that have
>   been granted local permissions.

In my understanding this container would only populate when you have AD forest and trust between two domain from different trees.